# How to map multiple root types for aggregate relations in NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, mapping, aggregate

Let's say I have a class Child which is contained in different other classes (ParentA and ParentB in this example). The following simple case demonstrates a simple model where ParentA and ParentB both contain a set of Child objects.

```
public class ParentA
{
    public virtual ISet<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class ParentB
{
    public virtual ISet<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
}
```

Navigation from parent to child is no problem in this simple case. But now I want to be able to navigate to the parent. Typically I would introduce an interface IParent)

```
public class ParentA: IParent
{
    public virtual ISet<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class ParentB
{
    public virtual ISet<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public virtual IParent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

The question now is how would you map such a relationship in NHibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ayende has a sample NHibernate Blog model. And `Tag` entity has a reference to its parent with property called `Entity`. Type of the `Entity` is `object`, and it is mapped either to be a `Post` or a `Blog`. Its might be what you are looking for.

All files in the model [here](https://github.com/ayende/nhibernate-blog-model/tree/master/Blog)
Tag [source](https://github.com/ayende/nhibernate-blog-model/blob/master/Blog/Tag.cs) and [mapping](https://github.com/ayende/nhibernate-blog-model/blob/master/Blog/Tag.hbm.xml)